# Applying AWK on Set of Files with Same Extension

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, file-globs

I want to apply the following "awk" command on files with extension "*.txt"

```
awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }'
```

But why this command doesn't work:

```
for i in *.txt do echo awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' $i; done
```

Normally,

```
awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' file1.txt
```

would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've removed the echo it should work:

```
for i in *.txt do awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' $i; done
```

It'll fail if there are any text files with spaces in them, you could try this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs --null -n 1 awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }'
```

An alternative for printing out names:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print -exec awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' {} \;
```

(Basically make find execute awk directly, so and also print out the file names.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way I can print out the filename also?

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in *.txt; do echo "$i"; awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' "$i"; done
```

This will print the names of the processed files together with the output of the `awk` command.

Comment: In Bash the 'for i in *.txt' works correctly also with spaces ($i contains the whole space-containing filename), but you are correct that this creates a problem when passing $i as an argument to awk. I've added the needed quotes around $i now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (use *nawk* or */usr/xpg4/bin/awk* on *Solaris*):

```
awk 'END {
  printf "%s: %.2f\n", fn, sum
  }
FNR == 1 {
  if (fn) printf "%s: %.2f\n", fn, sum
  fn = FILENAME
  sum = 0
  }
$4 ~ /NM/ { 
  sum += $2 
  }' *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a ';' :

```
for i in *.txt; do ...
```

instead of

```
for i in *.txt do ...
```

Answer (score 1):

echo is not required.

try

for i in *.txt; do; awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' $i; done

or

for i in *.txt; do awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' $i; done

should work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've copy pasted or it's a typo.

for i in *.txt do **echo** awk '$4 ~ /NM/{ sum += $2 } END{ print sum }' $i; done

With echo corrected, the command above will echo your awk script and the filename, but not run it.